# How do I get Azure Compute Emulator to run in 32 bit mode?

Tags: wcf, azure, fortran

So I found some articles here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere that show how to use Startup Tasks to set Azure to run in 32-bit mode.

The problem is, this doesn't seem to work with the Compute Emulator.

I wrote a Worker Role that runs a service which calls a legacy FORTRAN dll. This DLL, however, only runs in x86 mode. So, I need to force the Azure emulator to enable 32-bit apps.

I'm running on Windows 7 (or 8, if that works better), with either VS2010 or VS2012, and the error I am getting is "On this system, the Compute Emulator supports AnyCPU and x64."

Anyone have any great ideas?

Comment: You don't have source to that DLL?

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I hear that Azure runtime can run in 32-bit mode. The typical solution to this situation is to use some kind of interop and run the 32-bit code in a separate process - like a DCOM server or WCF service so that it doesn't matter whether Azure runtime runs in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.